iText 7, first item in my loop doesn't get formatted. Any idea why?
When I run my loop, it is supposed to format "res.position" ,and it does for every iteration of the loop except for the first one.
for(int i = 0; i < res.numJobs; i++) {
    document.add(new Paragraph(res.position[i]).setFont(montserrat1).setFontSize(10));
    document.add(new Paragraph(res.employer[i] + ", " + res.startDate[i] + " - " +res.endDate[i]))
            .setFont(montserrat1).setFontSize(10);
    document.add(new Paragraph( "• " + res.workDescription[i])).setFont(montserrat1).setFontSize(8).setFontColor(Color.GRAY);
}

Tried making it print in format, it did not print in format.

check the parenthesis ?? (e.g. the count of closing ) at the very end of each statement) {I really have no idea about iText, also did not fully understand the question, just a guess}

Simple parenthesis issue, should've looked harder before posting.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
